# SQL Server inner join returns the same row repeatedly in all the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am writing this query to do an `inner join`:

```
select firstname 
from employees  
inner join orders on Employees.employeeid = orders.employeeid
```

The result is the same row in all the columns.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: If that query is returning the same value for the entire dataset, then all your employees have the same firstname. Simply said.

Comment: so i think it just sorts the column by name and it contains the other names too

Comment: Check your column values and results before asking in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have more orders than you have employees.  Hence, one employee is on many orders.

When you run:

```
select e.firstname 
from employees e inner join
     orders o
     on e.employeeid = o.employeeid;
```

Then you are getting a list of all first names -- so one employee name is going to be repeated, once per each order.  If you want just a list of the *distinct* values, then you can use `select distinct` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because of more rows are related to that employee in orders table,
it may be help to understand:

```
SELECT Employees.firstname,Employees.employeeid,
orders.orderid,orders.employeeid
FROM employees
INNER JOIN orders
ON Employees.employeeid=orders.employeeid
```